# CakePHP 2.3 pagination named args

Tags: cakephp, routes, pagination

I create schema for my pagination:

```
Router::connect(__('news') .'/'. __('paginate') .'/:page', array(  
    'controller' => 'news',  
    'action' => 'index'), array(   
        'persist' => array(  
          'language')));
```

But 'named' params is still empty in Controller

My question is How to preapre router to work with pagination by links like this: news/paginate/4, news/paginate/5, etc...

I use Cake 2.3

Comment: I ask again: How to preapre router to work with pagination by links like this: news/paginate/4, news/paginate/5, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot used named params in routes.

Unrelated, you don't need the second argument `true` in calls to `__()` since 2.2. Check the API.

Comment: Pagination uses named parametr :page to portion results, but How create pagination for that?

Comment: Now I must use somelike this: $this->request->params['named']['page'] = $this->params['page']; Is better solutions?